# Auto scroll on tabbing to input leaving it partially hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table of rows and columns of elements, with each element containing either one or two input elements.

The table is constrained within the viewable area of the browser, through being contained inside a div which scrolls using `overflow-x`/`overflow-y` to show scroll bars.

---

My issue is when tabbing through each element. The tab order is correct, but when reaching the end of a horizontal row, it sometimes focuses on an input without fully scrolling to display it.

[image: Example of issue]

**Is there some way to easily have the whole input be scrolled to when tabbing?**

*The input can still be manually scrolled into view, there is no issue with the bounding area.

I am using Chrome, and only need to target this browser for this site.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate a event on the document to capture focus on `<input>` elements.  (The third parameter of `addEventListener()` needs to be true for this to work, because `focus` events don't bubble.)

Within the event listener, if the source is an `<input>`, determine its rightmost boundary using **[getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)**.  If it's larger than its scrolling container's width, adjust the container's `scrollLeft` as needed to show the entire `<input>`:

```
document.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
  var src = e.srcElement,
      sLeft = src.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      sRight = src.getBoundingClientRect().right,
      container,
      cWidth;

  if (src.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    container = src.parentNode;
    while(container && !/auto|scroll/.test(window.getComputedStyle(container)['overflow-x'])) {
      container = container.parentNode;
    }
    if(container) {
      cWidth = container.clientWidth;
      if (sRight > cWidth) {
        container.scrollLeft += sRight - cWidth;
      } else if (sLeft < 10) {  //10 accounts for scrollbar arrow
        container.scrollLeft += sLeft - 10;
      }
    }
  }
}, true);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
document.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
  var src = e.srcElement,
      sLeft = src.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      sRight = src.getBoundingClientRect().right,
      container,
      cWidth;

  if (src.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    container = src.parentNode;
    while(container && !/auto|scroll/.test(window.getComputedStyle(container)['overflow-x'])) {
      container = container.parentNode;
    }
    if(container) {
      cWidth = container.clientWidth;
      if (sRight > cWidth) {
        container.scrollLeft += sRight - cWidth;
      } else if (sLeft < 10) {  //10 accounts for scrollbar arrow
        container.scrollLeft += sLeft - 10;
      }
    }
  }
}, true);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

input {
  width: 140px;
}

input:focus {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      1 <input type="text">
      2 <input type="text">
      3 <input type="text">
      4 <input type="text">
      5 <input type="text">
      6 <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using Angular components, and this is a sub-component which doesn't know about the container element. Any way to do this with just the input element ref?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular, but you may need to walk up the document tree until you find the first element that has a scrollbar.

Comment: See my update, which now walks the document to determine the scrolling container.

Comment: I would prefer to do this without needing to go through the DOM structure, as we try not to access it in our code directly. I will try to see if there is some way of doing this through angular, but if not then will mark this as the answer. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onFocus event to scroll the div entirely into view.

Comment: Have tried doing so, but it is not having a noticeable effect.